# Custom created View

Tags: android, dynamic, android-custom-view, ondraw, custom-view

I have created a Custom View that displays the digits of a number in separate rectangular boxes :

[image]

The code for the `onDraw()` is as given below :

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    Rect rect = new Rect(20, 20, 170, 220);

    int xx = rect.left + 12;
    int yy = (rect.bottom - 25);

    int yyy = (rect.bottom +10);
    int xxx = (rect.left-10);

    for (int i = counter,j=0; i >= 0; i--,j++) {
        // Drawing the rectangle and using the rectangle as reference, drawing the digit.
        drawColoredDigit(canvas, rect, String.valueOf(digits[i]),xx,yy);
        // Updating the reference values for the rectangle, and in turn for the digits inside the reference.
        rect.left += (20 + 150);
        rect.right += (20 + 150);
        xx = (rect.left+ 20);
        xxx = (rect.left - 20);

        if(((counter-j)%3==0)&&(counter!=j))
        {
            canvas.drawText(",",xxx,yyy,commaPaint);
            rect.left += 20;
            rect.right += 20;
            xx = (rect.left + 20);
        }

    }
}

private void drawColoredDigit(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, String digit, int xx, int yy) {
    canvas.drawRect(rect, widgetPaint);
    canvas.drawText(digit, xx, yy, textPaint);
}
```

Is there a way i can make this code more dynamic so that the size of the rectangles in which the digits are rendered, is chosen, based on the length of the number. Also the size of the digits is then chosen based on the size of the rectangles, that are rendered.
Also the handling of the pixels on various devices needs to be handled.
Basically trying to make the View more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some implementations floating around of `TextView`s that automatically resize the text to fit the size of the view. My recommendation is to start with one of those and to use spans on the text instead of trying to draw the rectangles and things yourself. Take a look at [`ForegroundColorSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html) and [`BackgroundColorSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BackgroundColorSpan.html), and use a [`SpannableString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) to attach the spans to the text.